# CodeIgniter FTP Class to Create Remote File

Tags: php, codeigniter

how do we create file to the remote ftp from the CodeIgniter FTP Class.

I know how the dirictory are created

$this->ftp->mkdir($path.$name, DIR_WRITE_MODE);

I am looking same for creating file?

Comment: Just create it locally and upload it? I don't think there is any other way to do this in the FTP protocol

Comment: if you really need to do this, I would say use a shell script rather than php.

Comment: I don't know how to work this class but there is a good tut about FTP with PHP. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-work-with-php-and-ftp/

Comment: @Pekka: I am doing the same right now but if a simpler and faster way exist it will help me a lot as in my code i need to create and edit remote file very frequently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. FTP stands for File TRANSFER Protocol.
The easiest solution would be to create a (temp) file, upload it and then remove the local file.